# C# how to create a large byte array to a file

Tags: c#, arrays, file

Today I am struggling with finding a method to load a xex file from a byte array, the byte array is over 1200 lines long. Currently, I have a class called XeXFile where the byte array is stored and from my main form I want to load that byte array into a file and send it to my console, I have a class created to do this which works perfectly so my only issue is loading that byte array into a file.

Then send that to my console via this code.

```
SendFile(file location", @"where to send");
```

Thanks for the help in advance, never thought I would have struggled with this.

Comment: I dont understand your terminology. When bytes are written TO a file, it is called saving. When bytes are read FROM a file, it is called loading. Ergo, things are either "loaded from" or "saved to". What do you mean by LOADING INTO (a file)?

Comment: Sorry I should of been more clear, I already converted the xex file to a byte array, i just now need to create that byte array into a file. 


screen cap of the class for the byte array.

http://i.imgur.com/uB58FEL.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [System.IO.File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx)

Just use `File.WriteAllBytes` like this:

```
 String MyPath = @"C:\MyTestFolder\MyNewFile.xex";

 File.WriteAllBytes(MyPath, MybyteArray);
```

Important Note: This method creates a new file. If the file you specified in the
first parameter `MyPath` is already there, it will be overwritten!

Hope this helps you!